# How to create database in MySQL with numeric name?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to create a MySQL database with name as numerical value such as 123456
The query
`CREATE DATABASE 123456` 
or 
`CREATE DATABASE '123456'` is not working.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: You do not want to do this!!!

Comment: why?
I need to create the database with this name.
Is there any issues if I create a database with numeric name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to create a database with such a name, you should use backticks like:

```
CREATE DATABASE `12345`;
```

this works (at least for MySQL 5.5).
but it is a very VERY bad idea to do that. You should stick to descriptive names for databases/tables/columns.